# Strange orange bug in the garden with long legs

Tags: identification, insects, bug

There's these bugs that wander around my garden and I can't really tell what they're up to. I don't see any visible damage to the plants they loiter about on but they're all congregating on some cucumber plant pre fruiting, and in another instance they're all clustered on this ripe tomato just standing about it.

These little bugs are orange bodied with black spines protruding a bit. They have long black legs and long antennaes. They actually have incredible vision and are very responsive to objects drawing near to them and they're quite nimble and able to shuffle about fairly gracefully. They appear to have some kind of congregating behavior and they all show up together somehow. I don't really know where they came from all of a sudden, they don't have wings so I'm guessing they hatched somewhere nearby?

What are these bugs?

[image: orange bug on cucumber leaf]

[image: orange bug on tomato]

Comment: Fantastic photos.  I am curious to know what these are.

Comment: And I’d be (completely off topic) curios what kind of camera you used.

Comment: these were just taken with an iPhone13 in macro mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found them: Nymphs of leaf footed bug

Some people misidentify as nymphs of Assassin Bugs, which would be dangerous, but...

- https://durhammastergardeners.com/tag/orange-bugs
- https://www.hobbyfarms.com/is-that-bug-what-i-think-it-is/
- https://gardeningsolutions.ifas.ufl.edu/care/pests-and-diseases/pests/leaffooted-insect-pests.html

I had very bad stink bugs one year on my tomatoes, and they left marks on almost every fruit.  In my opinion, maybe try a dish soap spray to kill them.

Comment: yah that second link hits the nail on the head with this bit--*First, the legs of these particular insects were too short and dark in color. Second, the collective social behavior of the nymphs was very telling—assassin bugs tend to be solitary hunters unlike immature leaf-footed bugs, which stay clustered after hatching from their eggs*